# Replace speaker to retrieve audio signal (and isolate galvanically)

Tags: audio, transformer, isolation

I'd like to capture sound from a speaker output.
The system seems to be running with a small DC current (bias, so voltage across speaker is about 3 V), so the audio AC signal could be (de)coupled from a load resistor via a small capacitor.

The 10 kOhms resistor drops the 6.5 VDC (open circuit) to 5 VDC. The audio signal is in the order of 10 mVpp.

I would then need to amplify this signal and achieve some sort of galvanic isolation. Probably an opamp and a low frequency audio transformer (<1Vpp according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level).
However, this requires a power supply for the opamp which would be tricky to derive from the system, so I'd need an isolated dc-dc converter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5s51m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Audio quality is not a priority - a simple circuit is (one-off build).

If the "primary" circuit could be eliminated using a high impedance transformer directly, it would be even better. The secondary signal then could be brought to line level with a transimpedance amp.

Maybe a mains voltage relay coil with >10 kOhms could be used creatively (but: core? secondary?)? Is a high sensitivity hall-effect sensor a feasability?

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think you need amplification?  What level do you require at the output?   What *exactly* is the source system and how is it powered?  What *exactly* is the destination system and how is that powered?

Comment: Replacing a low impedance speaker with a high-value resistor means a small signal current which needs to be amplified. I will measure the signal level and update the question. Output level should be the 1Vpp I mentioned. Source system and its power source: unknown. I can only measure at the speaker. Destination system: ADC. Power probably 5 VDC.

Comment: On the contrary, if anything you'll probably need to attenuate.

Comment: What's your mysterious recording device? PC line in/mic in already have load resistors and coupling capacitors. You only need to try to not overdrive it. Maybe a resistive voltage divider is all you need.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Why do I need to attenuate a 10 mV signal (with 5V DC offset)?

Comment: @RaphaelP I would give the line in a try if it weren't for the 5 V dc offset my signal has. Also, this does not provide galvanic isolation.

Comment: The signal would not be 10mV unless you've turned down the volume on the source to nothing.  Look up what the voltage of a fractional watt signal on a speaker is.  As for the offset, read about the use of a series capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if "Audio quality is not a priority", why don't you keep the speaker and use a microphone for the recording? Choose a quiet room, night time and give it a try. Some post-recording noise removal in a software like Audacity would be a good thing.

It also checks all your requirements:

- Simple
- Galvanic isolation
- No additional power supply

Comment: Thanks, but I want to remove the speaker.